# Split string that includes multiline substrings into substrings

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

How can I split a string that may contain substrings that carry on to multiple lines into an array of strings by lines?

For example,

```
"1234","01",111,AreaA,10/10/2017 11:13:10,
    1,10/09/2017 18:45:00,23296151,"JOHN","- 11/09/2017 18:45:19  U JOHN 0036
  CONFIRMED",
    2,11/09/2017 14:25:00,23296151,"BECCA","- 11/09/2017 15:45:19  U BECCA 0036
  CONFIRMED",
```

Current code:

```
        string[] stringSeparators = { "\r\n" };
        string[] lines = auditMessage.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Returns:

```
""1234","01",111,AreaA,10/10/2017 11:13:10,"
"       1,10/09/2017 18:45:00,23296151,"JOHN","- 11/09/2017 18:45:19  U JOHN 0036"
"      CONFIRMED","
"       2,11/09/2017 14:25:00,23296151,"BECCA","- 11/09/2017 15:45:19  U BECCA 0036"
"      CONFIRMED","
```

What I would like to be returned:

```
""1234","01",111,AreaA,10/10/2017 11:13:10,"
"       1,10/09/2017 18:45:00,23296151,"JOHN","- 11/09/2017 18:45:19  U JOHN 0036 CONFIRMED","
"       2,11/09/2017 14:25:00,23296151,"BECCA","- 11/09/2017 15:45:19  U BECCA 0036 CONFIRMED","
```

Comment: What is the value of `stringSeparators`?

Comment: what is value for stringseparators

Comment: Would splitting on `,` be a possibility?

Comment: is that multipline string is sperated by new line character ...doent seems like that

Comment: Try splitting on `",\n"` and then remove all `\n` from your strings

Comment: @stuartd I've updated the OP

Comment: how do you fit your input into a variable?

Comment: If confirmed/unconfirmed is the last word in each record, then you can split your string by it.